# Cleaning a static char array after use

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I want my program to clean the static chars array for a new input I've tried with memset but it doesn't work or i'm doing it wrong. please some advice. Thanks in advance.

```
const char * password() {
     static int i = 0;
     static char pwd[STRING_LEN], c = '\0';
     static char return_buffer[255];

     memset(pwd, 0, sizeof pwd);     //<---
     memset(return_buffer, 0, sizeof return_buffer);     //<--

     printf("Password: ");
     while (i < STRING_LEN){
         pwd[i] = getch();
         c = pwd[i];
         if(c == 13) { break; }
         i++;
     }
     pwd[i] = '\0';

     snprintf(return_buffer, sizeof(return_buffer), "%s", pwd);
     printf("\n");
     return return_buffer;
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: You'll write the `'\0'` outside the array if the user enters `STRING_LEN` characters. You need `while (i < STRING_LEN - 1)` to leave room for the null.

Comment: `if(c == 13)` looks suspicious.

Comment: That depends on the platform.

Comment: in my case i tried to use '\n' and the result was a crash XD so im sticking with 13

Comment: 13 is not `'\n'` but `'\r'` (carriage return). Since you use `getch()` i suspect you are on windows where a "newline" consists of `'\r'` and `'\n'`, so checking for `'\r'` (= 13) is the right(tm) thing to do. Neither, `'\r'` nor `'\n'` should result in a crash, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that there is no need to "clean" the arrays since you are overwriting their content with the result of `getch()` and a `'\0'` ... you never reset `i`.

`i` is a static `int` that only will get initialized the first time, execution passes its point of definition. Also, there is no need for `i` and `pwd` to be static variables.

Comment: Why does he need to reset `i`?

Comment: Because he surely doesn't want input being written behind former input at a 2nd, 3rd, ... call to the function.

Comment: `i` is a static int.  Subsequent calls to the function will keep incrementing without resetting it back to 0.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the `static` declaration.

Comment: The answer should go into more detail about how static variable initialization works. There's also no need for `i` and `pwd` to be static at all. The only variable that needs to be static is `return_buffer`, since it's being returned.

Comment: its done! thanks! it was the i variable, and the pwd[] and c dont needed to be static